# How to access contents of QComboBox?(PyQT5)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Here is what I am trying to do

Pseudocode:

```
if QCombobox[currentOption] == "option so and so": 
       do something
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
 def modeChange(self):
        content = self.combo_box.currentText()
        if self.Change.isChecked():
          if content == "Rule of 72":
              self.head.show()
```

From this code, I want my application to check if the currentbox is at that specific option, if it is, show the head label, otherwise, show nothing when other options are selected

for context, this is what head refers to(as well as info on combobox variable):

```
        self.combo_box = QComboBox(self)
        self.combo_box.setGeometry(0, 0, 241, 61)
        choices = ["Interest Rate","Net Profit Margin", "Rule of 72","Cash Flow", "Gains/Losses","Break-Even Equation"]
        self.combo_box.addItems(choices)
        self.combo_box.hide()

        self.head = QLabel("Rule of 72", self)
        self.head.setGeometry(0, 10, 400, 60)
        self.head.hide()
```

My full code:

```
class CalculatorWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Calculator):
    firstNum = None
    userIsTypingSecondNumber = False


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

        #Connect buttons
        self.Zero.clicked.connect(self.digit_pressed)
        self.One.clicked.connect(self.digit_pressed)
        self.Two.clicked.connect(self.digit_pressed)
        self.Three.clicked.connect(self.digit_pressed)
        self.Four.clicked.connect(self.digit_pressed)
        self.Five.clicked.connect(self.digit_pressed)
        self.Six.clicked.connect(self.digit_pressed)
        self.Seven.clicked.connect(self.digit_pressed)
        self.Eight.clicked.connect(self.digit_pressed)
        self.Nine.clicked.connect(self.digit_pressed)

        self.period.clicked.connect(self.period_pressed)

        self.Sign.clicked.connect(self.unary_pressed)
        self.Percent.clicked.connect(self.unary_pressed)

        self.Plus.clicked.connect(self.op_pressed)
        self.Minus.clicked.connect(self.op_pressed)
        self.Multiply.clicked.connect(self.op_pressed)
        self.Divide.clicked.connect(self.op_pressed)

        self.Equal.clicked.connect(self.Equal_pressed)

        self.Clear.clicked.connect(self.clear_pressed)
        self.Plus.setCheckable(True)
        self.Minus.setCheckable(True)
        self.Multiply.setCheckable(True)
        self.Divide.setCheckable(True)
        self.Percent.setChecked(True)
        self.Sign.setChecked(True)

        self.Change.clicked.connect(self.change_pressed)
        self.Change.setCheckable(True)

        self.modeChange()

    def period_pressed(self):
        self.label.setText(self.label.text() + '.')


    def op_pressed(self):
        button = self.sender()
        self.firstNum = float(self.label.text())
        button.setChecked(True)


    def change_pressed(self):
        if self.Change.isChecked():
            self.label.hide()
            self.Change.setText("")
            self.Clear.hide()
            self.Equal.hide()
            self.Divide.hide()
            self.Multiply.hide()
            self.Minus.hide()
            self.Plus.hide()
            self.Percent.hide()
            self.Sign.hide()
            self.period.hide()
            self.Zero.hide()
            self.One.hide()
            self.Two.hide()
            self.Three.hide()
            self.Four.hide()
            self.Five.hide()
            self.Six.hide()
            self.Seven.hide()
            self.Eight.hide()
            self.Nine.hide()
            self.combo_box.show()
        else:
            self.label.show()
            self.label.setText("0")
            self.Change.setText("")
            self.Clear.show()
            self.Clear.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                     "  background-color: rgb(215, 215, 215);\n"
                                     "  border: 1px solid gray;\n"
                                     "}\n"
                                     "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
                                     "    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
                                     "                                      stop: 0 #BEBEBE, stop: 1 #D7D7D7);\n"
                                     "}")
            self.Equal.show()
            self.Equal.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                     "  background-color: rgb(255, 151, 57);\n"
                                     "  color: white; \n"
                                     "  border: 1px solid gray;\n"
                                     "}\n"
                                     "\n"
                                     "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
                                     "    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
                                     "                                      stop: 0 #FF7832, stop: 1 #FF9739);\n"
                                     "}")
            self.Divide.show()
            self.Divide.setText("/")
            self.Divide.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                      "  background-color: rgb(255, 151, 57);\n"
                                      "  color: white; \n"
                                      "  border: 1px solid gray;\n"
                                      "}\n"
                                      "\n"
                                      "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
                                      "    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
                                      "                                      stop: 0 #FF7832, stop: 1 #FF9739);\n"
                                      "}")
            self.Multiply.show()
            self.Multiply.setText("*")
            self.Multiply.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                        "  background-color: rgb(255, 151, 57);\n"
                                        "  color: white; \n"
                                        "  border: 1px solid gray;\n"
                                        "}\n"
                                        "\n"
                                        "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
                                        "    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
                                        "                                      stop: 0 #FF7832, stop: 1 #FF9739);\n"
                                        "}")
            self.Minus.show()
            self.Minus.setText("-")
            self.Minus.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                     "  background-color: rgb(255, 151, 57);\n"
                                     "  color: white; \n"
                                     "  border: 1px solid gray;\n"
                                     "}\n"
                                     "\n"
                                     "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
                                     "    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
                                     "                                      stop: 0 #FF7832, stop: 1 #FF9739);\n"
                                  
                                     "}")
            self.Plus.show()
            self.Plus.setText("+")
            self.Plus.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                    "  background-color: rgb(255, 151, 57);\n"
                                    "  color: white; \n"
                                    "  border: 1px solid gray;\n"
                                    "}\n"
                                    "\n"
                                    "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
                                    "    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
                                    "                                      stop: 0 #FF7832, stop: 1 #FF9739);\n"
                                    "}")
            self.Percent.show()
            self.Percent.setText("%")
            self.Percent.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                       "  background-color: rgb(215, 215, 215);\n"
                                       "  border: 1px solid gray;\n"
                                       "}\n"
                                       "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
                                       "    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
                                       "                                      stop: 0 #BEBEBE, stop: 1 #D7D7D7);\n"
                                       "}")
            self.Sign.show()
            self.Sign.setText("+/-")
            self.Sign.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                    "  background-color: rgb(215, 215, 215);\n"
                                    "  border: 1px solid gray;\n"
                                    "}\n"
                                    "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
                                    "    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
                                    "                                      stop: 0 #BEBEBE, stop: 1 #D7D7D7);\n"
                                    "}")
            self.period.show()
            self.period.setText(".")
            self.period.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                      "   border: 1px solid gray;\n"
                                      "}\n"
                                      "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
                                      "    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
                                      "                                      stop: 0 #dadbde, stop: 1 #f6f7fa);\n"
                                      "}\n"
                                      "")
            self.Zero.show()
            self.Zero.setText("0")
            self.Zero.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                    "   border: 1px solid gray;\n"
                                    "}\n"
                                    "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
                                    "    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
                                    "                                      stop: 0 #dadbde, stop: 1 #f6f7fa);\n"
                                    "}\n"
                                    "")
            self.One.show()
            self.One.setText("1")
            self.One.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                    "   border: 1px solid gray;\n"
                                    "}\n"
                                    "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
                                    "    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
                                    "                                      stop: 0 #dadbde, stop: 1 #f6f7fa);\n"
                                    "}\n"
                                    "")
            self.Two.show()
            self.Two.setText("2")
            self.Two.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                    "   border: 1px solid gray;\n"
                                    "}\n"
                                    "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
                                    "    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
                                    "                                      stop: 0 #dadbde, stop: 1 #f6f7fa);\n"
                                    "}\n"
                                    "")
            self.Three.show()
            self.Three.setText("3")
            self.Three.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                   "   border: 1px solid gray;\n"
                                   "}\n"
                                   "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
                                   "    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
                                   "                                      stop: 0 #dadbde, stop: 1 #f6f7fa);\n"
                                   "}\n"
                                   "")
            self.Four.show()
            self.Four.setText("4")
            self.Four.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                    "   border: 1px solid gray;\n"
                                    "}\n"
                                    "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
                                    "    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
                                    "                                      stop: 0 #dadbde, stop: 1 #f6f7fa);\n"
                                    "}\n"
                                    "")
            self.Five.show()
            self.Five.setText("5")
            self.Five.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                   "   border: 1px solid gray;\n"
                                   "}\n"
                                   "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
                                   "    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
                                   "                                      stop: 0 #dadbde, stop: 1 #f6f7fa);\n"
                                   "}\n"
                                   "")
            self.Six.show()
            self.Six.setText("6")
            self.Six.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                   "   border: 1px solid gray;\n"
                                   "}\n"
                                   "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
                                   "    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
                                   "                                      stop: 0 #dadbde, stop: 1 #f6f7fa);\n"
                                   "}\n"
                                   "")
            self.Seven.show()
            self.Seven.setText("7")
            self.Seven.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                     "   border: 1px solid gray;\n"
                                     "}\n"
                                     "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
                                     "    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
                                     "                                      stop: 0 #dadbde, stop: 1 #f6f7fa);\n"
                                     "}\n"
                                     "")
            self.Eight.show()
            self.Eight.setText("8")
            self.Eight.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                   "   border: 1px solid gray;\n"
                                   "}\n"
                                   "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
                                   "    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
                                   "                                      stop: 0 #dadbde, stop: 1 #f6f7fa);\n"
                                   "}\n"
                                   "")
            self.Nine.show()
            self.Nine.setText("9")
            self.Nine.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                     "   border: 1px solid gray;\n"
                                     "}\n"
                                     "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
                                     "    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
                                     "                                      stop: 0 #dadbde, stop: 1 #f6f7fa);\n"
                                     "}\n"
                                     "")
            self.combo_box.hide()






    def digit_pressed(self):
       if not self.Change.isChecked():
           button = self.sender()
           if ((self.Plus.isChecked() or self.Minus.isChecked() or
                self.Multiply.isChecked() or self.Divide.isChecked()) and (not self.userIsTypingSecondNumber)):
               newLabel = format(float(button.text()), '.15g')
               self.userIsTypingSecondNumber = True
           else:
               if (('.' in self.label.text()) and (button.text() == "0")):
                   newLabel = format((self.label.text() + button.text()), '.15')
               else:
                   newLabel = format(float(self.label.text() + button.text()), '.15g')

           self.label.setText(newLabel)

    def unary_pressed(self):
        if not self.Change.isChecked():
            button = self.sender()
            labelNumber = float(self.label.text())
            if button.text() == '+/-':
                labelNumber = labelNumber * -1
            else:
                labelNumber = labelNumber * 0.1

            newLabel = format(labelNumber, '.15g')
            self.label.setText(newLabel)

    def Equal_pressed(self):
        secondNum = float(self.label.text())
        if not self.Change.isChecked():
            if self.Plus.isChecked():
                labelNumber = self.firstNum + secondNum
                newLabel = format(labelNumber, '.15g')
                self.label.setText(newLabel)
                self.Plus.setChecked(False)
            elif self.Minus.isChecked():
                labelNumber = self.firstNum - secondNum
                newLabel = format(labelNumber, '.15g')
                self.label.setText(newLabel)
                self.Minus.setChecked(False)
            elif self.Multiply.isChecked():
                labelNumber = self.firstNum * secondNum
                newLabel = format(labelNumber, '.15g')
                self.label.setText(newLabel)
                self.Multiply.setChecked(False)
            elif self.Divide.isChecked():
                labelNumber = self.firstNum/secondNum
                newLabel = format(labelNumber, '.15g')
                self.label.setText(newLabel)
                self.Divide.setChecked(False)

        self.userIsTypingSecondNumber = False

    def clear_pressed(self):
        self.Plus.setChecked(False)
        self.Minus.setChecked(False)
        self.Multiply.setChecked(False)
        self.Divide.setChecked(False)
        self.userIsTypingSecondNumber = False
        self.label.setText("0")

    def modeChange(self):
        content = self.combo_box.currentText()
        if self.Change.isChecked():
          if content == "Rule of 72":
              self.head.show()
```

Comment: Please always try to provide a [mre]. Almost 80% of your code is completely irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `currentTextChanged` signal.

```
self.combo_box.currentTextChanged.connect(self.modeChange)

def modeChange(self, text):
    if self.Change.isChecked():
        if text == "Rule of 72":
            self.head.show()
        else:
            self.head.hide()
```